# Many-to-Many Merge in one big data step

Tags: sas

I'm working on creating three datasets from a many to many merge. I know that I need to select the team name from the player variable to create a team variable in one of the datasets so that it can match up with the other dataset (or can I do it by rank? I don't know, really.). However, creating this variable in the same dataset as I am supposed to merge is making this difficult. 
An example for the player variable might be: "Jamal San Quentin, Kentucky St."
I need to extract the Kentucky St. part (I'm thinking scan function with a delimiter) so that it can be matched up with Kentucky St. (which is "Name" in the other data set). I am renaming "Name" into "Team" and creating "Team" from the variable "Player" in the other set. However, I can't seem to make it all work together...

```
data wpa.ALLDATA work.TeamData work.NoRunners;
    length team $20;
    Team = scan(Player,2,',');
    merge downl.runners (in=r) downl.offences (in=o rename=(name=Team) 
    drop=ties);
    by Team;
    if r and o then output work.TeamData;
    else if o and not r then output work.NoRunners;
    else if o or r then output wpa.ALLDATA;
run;
```

The alldata should have 136, the Teamdata should have 100, and norunners should have 36. My problem is that the sets just aren't merging on the basis of team, even after sorting and doing Team as a by variable.

Comment: Please provide some sample rows from the input datasets and the intended output dataset.

Comment: There are a few observations from the base sets.

Comment: Post as text please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `MERGE` the variable has to exist in the input data step.  The merge happens before any user statements like `SCAN()` can operate.

```
data team_runners ;
  set runners;
  length team $20;
  team = left(scan(player,2,','));
  player = scan(player,1,',');
run;
proc sort data=team_runners ;
  by team player;
run;
```

Now you can merge the new `TEAM_RUNNERS` table with your existing `OFFENCES` by the new `TEAM` variable.

Your actual merge is NOT a many-to-many merge.  Since any record from your team/player table will only match to at most one record in your team offense table. You can then split the result into three groups: matches, unmatched players and unmatched teams.  To include a table with all records just use an non-conditional OUTPUT statement.

```
 data allrecords matches noteam noplayers ;
   merge team_players(in=in1) offences(in=in2);
   by team;
   output allrecords;
   if in1 and in2 then output matches;
   else if in1 then output noteam ;
   else output noplayers;
 run;
```

Comment: Tom, thanks again for the help. Most of it is working. However, when selecting the output to data sets, I need one data set with 136 observations (the one that isn't a direct match, but has both data sets' observations in it). This one gives me the noteam data set with 0 observations. How can we change that?                                               data matches alldata norunners ;
merge team_runners(in=in1) offences(in=in2);
   by team;
   if in1 and in2 then output matches;
   else if in2 and not in1 then output norunners ;
   else if in1 or in2 than output alldata;
 run;

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but if you want that third group to be different than (in1 and not in2) then you need to remove the ELSE.  In fact since your specifications for all three groups are complete then remove both ELSE keywords.  IF (in1 or in2) is every records, so there is no need for the IF statement, just use a bare output.

Comment: ^That sounds like a plan. Thanks for all of your help, Tom.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more efficient way. This solution uses a hash object and a hash iterator. You can always run 2 data steps and separate the team name from the players name first and proceed like you did in a second step. The following does all at once.

```
data runners;
length Team $16.;
input Team $ Var1 Var2;
datalines;
Name1,TeamName1 1 2
Name2,TeamName2 1 3
Name1,TeamName3 2 4
Name2,TeamName4 2 4
Name2,TeamName5 2 4
;
run;

data offences;
length Name $10.;
input Name $ Var3 Var4;
datalines;
TeamName1 1 2
TeamName2 1 3
TeamName3 2 4
TeamName4 2 4
TeamName6 2 4
;
run;


data ALLDATA TeamData NoRunners (drop=rc);
if 0 then set runners;
if _N_ =1 then
do;
    declare hash hh(ordered:'A');
    declare hiter hi('hh');
    hh.definekey('Team');
    hh.definedata('Team','Var1','Var2','Name');
    hh.definedone();
end;

do while(not theend);
    set runners (rename=(Team=TeamName)) end=theend;
    Team = prxchange("s/^(.+),//",-1,TeamName);
    Name = prxchange("s/,(.+)$//",-1,TeamName);
    hh.ref();
    drop TeamName;
end;

do while(not last);
    set offences (rename=(Name=Team)) end=last;
    rc= hh.find();

    if rc =0 then do;
            output TeamData ALLDATA;
            hh.remove();
        end;
    else do;
        call missing(Var1,Var2,Name);
        output NoRunners ALLDATA;
    end;
end;

rc = hi.first();
do while(rc=0);
    output ALLDATA;
    rc = hi.next();
end;
stop;
run;
```

Comment: I don't understand any of this and have never seen a hash object or hash iterator before. Ideally, there could be something using sorting and renaming, but keeping it simple and in only a data step or two. You clearly do know quite a lot about the language, but it's a little quick for me.

Comment: Then the solution Tom provided is probably best for you. The variable team has to exist in the file before merging. SAS treats observation by observation, it loops over every row in the dataset. And you need to define the input of a datastep (set, merge,... ) before you can work with the variables in the input file. I thought you wanted it in one datastep. After all the title of the post suggests it... :D